# Looping over dataset of strings

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm trying to pick out specific occurrences of a value in a dataset of mine, but keep running into a problem dealing with turning the values into strings and looping over them. My code is below:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('DurhamAirMass.txt')
spot = data[:,1]
mass = str(data[:,2])


DP = np.array([])
DT = np.array([])
MP = np.array([])
MT = np.array([])
TR = np.array([])

for i in range(1461):
    if mass[i] == '2':
        DP = np.append(DP, str(spot[i]))
    if mass[i] == '3':
        DT = np.append(DT, str(spot[i]))
    if mass[i] == '5':
        MP = np.append(MP, str(spot[i]))
    if mass[i] == '6' or '66' or '67':
        MT = np.append(MT, str(spot[i]))
    if mass[i] == '7':
        TR = np.append(TR, str(spot[i]))    

print DP
```

When I attempt to print out the DP array, I get an error pointing at the first if statement and saying "IndexError: string index out of range". Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know that ``mass`` is always going to be at least length ``1461``? I would think that your for loop should be ``for i in range(len(mass))``

Comment: @aruisdante I think this is where I'm running into the problem. The strings aren't of length 1461, that's how many data points I have to loop over (i.e. I have 1461 masses and 1461 spots)

Comment: do a `print mass` and look, what's it look like.

Comment: @Daniel It gives me 1461 different numbers (i.e. the first six are [1. 4. 7. 2. 2. 2. ..........]

Comment: @DJV: no, it gives you a string representation of the array and the length is about 80 characters

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of converting `data[:,2]` into a string?
Btw.  `or` does not work as you think, you have to repeat `mass[i]==``

Why not:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('DurhamAirMass.txt')
mass = data[:, 1]
spot = data[:, 2]
DP = mass[spot == 2]
DT = mass[spot == 3]
MP = mass[spot == 5]
MT = mass[(spot == 6)||(spot == 66)||(spot == 67)]
TR = mass[spot == 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed causing an `IndexError`

try checking `spot` to see how large it is, my guess is that `1461` is larger then its bounds perhaps you could try setting your `for` loop as:

```
for i in range(len(spot)):
    ...
```

instead, this will garauntee that you will only access valid Indexes for `spot`, if this still causes a problem try the same for `mass`

```
for i in range(len(mass)):
    ...
```

You could also add a check to make sure the data is the length you think it is.

```
print len(mass), len(spot), len(spot) == len(mass)
```

It's always good practice to double check your assumptions in the case of an error.  In this case you are clearly being told there is an `IndexError` so the next step is to find out what index is causing it.

Maybe more information would help you?

```
try:
    for i in range(len(spot)):
        # code as usual
except:
    print i
    raise e
```

This will tell you what index is causing the error.

Comment: "spot" and "mass" both have 1461 values. As I said in the comment above, I think the program is thinking that 'mass' is 1461 characters long, which it is not. There are simply 1461 mass values.

Comment: @DJV Ok, but an `IndexError` means you are trying to access something out of bounds of the object you are trying to access.  Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @DJV see my edit, also could you provide the exact error message? perhaps also the index upon which you are getting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should never hard-code for-loop iterations unless you want it to be considered an error for the input iterator to ever be greater/smaller than your hard-coded value (and even then, there are better ways to accomplish that).

Your code should probably look like this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    ...
```

This will ensure you always loop over only the data you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed all the strings to ints and that solved things. I didn't think that would work at first. Thanks for all of your answers, everyone!